# Charging two wet cell batteries in parallel from an alternator

Tags: batteries

If I charge two wet cell batteries in parallel from an alternator and the smaller starter battery only needs a short charge to reach full state of charge and the service battery requires a long charging time, will this cause problems for the starter battery or are all the amps produced by the alternator directed to the service batteries when the starter battery is full ?

Answer (score 0):

It does depend on the condition of each of the batteries but the charging of each of the batteries can be thought to "keep pace" with one another because the charging current will depend on the voltage of a battery, its internal resistance and the applied voltage due to the charger.

Although you may think that the smaller battery will charge faster because there are less chemicals in it that is not necessarily so because that would increase its voltage faster but its larger voltage would reduce the charging current through it, thus reducing the rate at which it is charged.